# Can't figure out Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php

I got error in this line

```
Public boolean hasNext(){
  return nextNode != null;
}
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\wamp\www\pm\test6.php on line 61

Comment: it is 'Public' rather

Comment: Get rid of `boolean`

Comment: The error is almost certainly caused by the line before this not being right, but the presence of "boolean" suggests that this isn't even PHP...

Comment: here's the code above the error one.still don't get it, sorry.  
function testinput($data){
$data = trims($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
removeOK == false;
posToRemove == -1;
}

Public boolean hasNext(){
 return nextNode != null;
}